# Minecraft doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, launcher, openjdk, minecraft

I recently updated to Ubuntu 18.04 and can't get Minecraft to work.

The launcher works fine using both Java 8 and Java 11 runtime, but when I click Play, one of two things happens: either the launcher reverts back to the click to play screen, or the whole thing just shuts down and does nothing.

If the launcher reverts, the game output tab says this:

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Unrecognized VM option 'CMSIncrementalMode'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

My launcher version is 1.6.89-j, and I am trying to play Minecraft 1.13. The launcher always says it's "ready to update & play Minecraft 1.13", rather than just play it. My .minecraft file is copied over from when I was using Ubuntu 16.04, where it worked fine.

I know almost nothing about programming in java or any other language, so please keep your answers detailed and idiot-proof.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I am having the same problem. It will work using openjdk-8 but it's very slow. Something is wrong. I'm trying to compile openjdk-8 from source but it's hopeless; openjdk-8 compiling from source is not for the novice like me. I don't yet have a solution so I hope somebody answers this question. Seems VERY odd that Minecraft won't work on Ubuntu 18.04 out of the box!!